# Drupal 6 schema not installing all tables

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

So this has been driving me crazy for 2 days, I have a module I've written that uses 3 DB tables, 2 of them install perfectly, and this is the third one:

```
$schema['tags_twistal'] = array(
    'description' => t('Taxonomy for videos (tags)'),
    'fields' => array(
        'vid' => array(
            'description' => t('The video ID'),
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'length' => 255,
            'not null' => TRUE,
        ),
        'tag' => array(
            'description' => t('The tag name'),
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'length' => 255,
            'not null' => TRUE,
        ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('tag','vid'),
);
```

All I can think is that it has something to do with the primary key that I set, I've also tried:

```
'unique keys' => array(
    'tag_vid' => array('tag', 'vid'),
),
'primary key' => array('tag_vid'),
```

Any ideas? I'm about to pull my hair out!

Comment: Why do you need to set tag as the primary key ? Set only "vid" (which i believe same as nid) as primary. "tag_vid" usage is wrong.

Comment: vid and nid have nothing to do with each other, it's not a version of a node, or a node itself, otherwise I would just use the built in taxonomy tables. A video can have more than 1 tag, but I want to make sure when the db is updated there aren't 2 identical rows, I've also tried just using the "unique keys" and leaving out "primary key" and it still fails

Comment: In a nutshell, you're trying to create a primary key that's too long.   [This article](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/17/max-key-length-in-mysql/) explains it very well and pretty much matches your example perfectly

Comment: that's good to know, but that wasn't the problem, I was able to create the table by executing the query outside of the schema hook with no problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue in Drupal 7.

The tables of mine that install correctly are those which have a matching entry in the array returned by hook_node_info().

It looks as though Drupal will not create any tables that are not referenced in hook_node_info(), even if they are explicitly enumerated in hook_scheme(). I can't find this documented anywhere, but it matches my experience, and is a pain in the butt.

Comment: Oh, another thing, Drupal likes to hide errors that happen during installation.

Whack an "exit" statement at the end of your hook_install() implementation, uninstall and reinstall your module. If the database is kicking up an error, it'll show it there.